# Android - activity restarts on Notification click(the notification has been opened a foreground service)

Tags: android, service, notifications, foreground-service

I have a service which has been defined as follows

```
public class ForegroundService extends Service {
private static final String LOG_TAG = "ForegroundService";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if(intent != null) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Received Start Foreground Intent ");
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, DashboardActivity.class);
            notificationIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplication(),
                    0,
                    notificationIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);

            Intent previousIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
            previousIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION);
            PendingIntent ppreviousIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                    previousIntent, 0);

            Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
            playIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION);
            PendingIntent pplayIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                    playIntent, 0);

            Intent nextIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
            nextIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION);
            PendingIntent pnextIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                    nextIntent, 0);

            Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.art_background);

            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("Truiton Music Player")
                    .setTicker("Truiton Music Player")
                    .setContentText("My Music")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setLargeIcon(
                            Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, 128, 128, false))
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous,
                            "Previous", ppreviousIntent)
                    .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play, "Play",
                            pplayIntent)
                    .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_next, "Next",
                            pnextIntent).build();
            startForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE,
                    notification);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Previous");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Play");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Next");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(
                Constants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Received Stop Foreground Intent");
            stopForeground(true);
            stopSelf();
        }
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "In onDestroy");
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // Used only in case of bound services.
    return null;
}
}
```

I have defined the following in my manifest

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

And

this is how i am starting the service

```
private void showNotificationService() {
    Intent startIntent = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, ForegroundService.class);
    startIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
    startService(startIntent);
}
```

So when I click the notification the application goes to the onCreate, but I want app to resume to what state it was in before the notification showed up. Any clue as to what I am doing wrong?

Also I am using the code provided in this blog for the foreground service

http://www.truiton.com/2014/10/android-foreground-service-example/

Answer (score 0):

Add the category to your notificationIntent

Refer below code

```
notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some modifications to your code. The problem was when you were creating the new Intent.

```
public class ForegroundService extends Service {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ForegroundService";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if(intent != null) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Received Start Foreground Intent ");
                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, DashboardActivity.class);
                notificationIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
                notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplication(),
                        0,
                        notificationIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                Intent previousIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
                previousIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION);
                PendingIntent ppreviousIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                        previousIntent, 0);

                Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
                playIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION);
                PendingIntent pplayIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                        playIntent, 0);

                Intent nextIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
                nextIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION);
                PendingIntent pnextIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                        nextIntent, 0);

                Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.art_background);

                Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setContentTitle("Truiton Music Player")
                        .setTicker("Truiton Music Player")
                        .setContentText("My Music")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setLargeIcon(
                                Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, 128, 128, false))
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setOngoing(true)
                        .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous,
                                "Previous", ppreviousIntent)
                        .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play, "Play",
                                pplayIntent)
                        .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_next, "Next",
                                pnextIntent).build();
                startForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE,
                        notification);
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION)) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Previous");
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION)) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Play");
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION)) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Next");
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(
                    Constants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Received Stop Foreground Intent");
                stopForeground(true);
                stopSelf();
            }
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "In onDestroy");
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // Used only in case of bound services.
        return null;
    }
    }
```

I have defined the following in my manifest

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

I can work for you. I did it and I worked! If you need something else or more help, I am available. Have a nice day!